# (I start to think/thinking ...) or (I'm starting to think/thinking ...)?

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous

> A: Are you going to the party tonight? Marsha says she's coming.
>
> B: Marsha? No, I'll just stay at home.
>
> A: I ___ to think/thinking you hate her.

Which one is more probable? The present simple or the present continuous?

Comment: I **think** you hate her.

Comment: **I'm starting to think...**